# fitting images to container in grid without specifying column widths

Tags: html, css

I am creating a horizontal grid which is supposed to hold thumbnails.  I want each thumbnail to automatically scale itself to the height of the container.  I can get it to work for the first thumbnail, but for some reason it takes up the entire width of the container and the remaining thumbnails are not shown.

Here is what it looks like.

```css
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

.container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vw;
}

.img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.img1 {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/170x/77/27/41/772741907c120ab4cf766a3da9da6fcb.jpg');
}

.img2 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.britannica.com/s:225x120/95/156695-131-FF89C9FA/oak-tree.jpg');
}
  
.img3 {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/8f/f0/b48ff0b8dadf61c80f9f859d8ee8529c.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller container1">
  <div class="img img1"></div>
  <div class="img img2"></div>
  <div class="img img3"></div>
</div>
```

This is more what I want it to look like:

```css
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

.container2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vw;
}

.img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.img1 {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/170x/77/27/41/772741907c120ab4cf766a3da9da6fcb.jpg');
}

.img2 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.britannica.com/s:225x120/95/156695-131-FF89C9FA/oak-tree.jpg');
}
  
.img3 {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/8f/f0/b48ff0b8dadf61c80f9f859d8ee8529c.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller container2">
  <div class="img img1"></div>
  <div class="img img2"></div>
  <div class="img img3"></div>
</div>
```

*Except* that I don't want to have to define fixed column widths!  I want the width to be whatever it needs to be when the image is scaled to the full height of the container.  If I add or remove elements it should still work without having to recalculate the widths of each column.

After playing around with it a bit more I discovered that *for this particular set of images* I can get something pretty close to what I want by adding a bunch of `1fr` columns:

```css
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

.container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vw;
}

.img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.img1 {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/170x/77/27/41/772741907c120ab4cf766a3da9da6fcb.jpg');
}

.img2 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.britannica.com/s:225x120/95/156695-131-FF89C9FA/oak-tree.jpg');
}
  
.img3 {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/8f/f0/b48ff0b8dadf61c80f9f859d8ee8529c.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller container1">
  <div class="img img1"></div>
  <div class="img img2"></div>
  <div class="img img3"></div>
</div>
```

However this only works specifically with this height and image sizes, if I (for instance) double the height I would have to figure out how many `1 fr` columns to remove.  And it still has extra whitespace in the last element.

Comment: My updated solution should give you what you want, and it's responsive thanks for flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussions in the comments here is a solution with the images in the html and just the styling in css (which is semantically a bit more appropriate for this use case).

codepen.io/tcurdt/pen/WNwMgwB

```
<<div class="scroller">
  <!--
--><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/170x/77/27/41/772741907c120ab4cf766a3da9da6fcb.jpg" />
  <!--
--><img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/s:225x120/95/156695-131-FF89C9FA/oak-tree.jpg" />
  <!--
--><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b4/8f/f0/b48ff0b8dadf61c80f9f859d8ee8529c.png" />
</div>
```

```
:root {
  //--height: 300px;
  --height: 100vh;
}

.scroller {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  overflow: scroll;
  height: var(--height);
}

.scroller > img {
  height: var(--height);
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

The important bit is to define the columns of the grid track according to the content size. Unfortunately this means that a complete auto flow is not possible (IIUC the spec correctly). So you will have to adjust the number of images in the `repeat`.

By defining just the height of the child elements (`img`), the aspect ratio is kept intact.

The comments are always a good measure to remove the whitespace that can create some problems with some designs. It's not really necessary if you compress the css.

Comment: can i get rid of the extra space between images? (everything but the border)

Comment: May I ask why it is weird to generate images using CSS? I'm simply curious, nothing else :)

Comment: @LaurentC to be honest, the reason i'm using CSS images is because i was having a boatload of problems getting any other solution working when the div was inside of another element set at display:grid, so i decided to just make the container div conform to that as well and the CSS background  was how I got it to at least work this far...

Comment: @Michael Your example had the space as well. You want the columns to match the width of the images IIUC?

Comment: @tcurdt Yes, after scaling the images so that the height matches the parent container and the aspect ratio is preserved

Comment: @Michael Like this? https://codepen.io/tcurdt/pen/WNwMgwB

Comment: @tcurdt Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

RE-Updated flexbox solution. OP asked to be usable with any foramt of pictures. So we set background-size to cover and background-position to center center which gives the desired result

https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/YzqevVo

```css
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;  /* set the display to flexbox */
  justify-content:space-around; /*tell flexbox to use the space evenly between each item and each sides */
  width: 100vw;

}

.img {
   border:2px solid black;width:33.333vw;
 height:33.333vw; /*give a width to your images  that is relative */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.img1 {
  border:4px solid black;
  border-right:2px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://dev.laurentchevrette.digital/images/pano1.jpg');
}

.img2 {
  border-top:4px solid black;
  border-bottom:4px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://dev.laurentchevrette.digital/images/pano2.jpg');
}
  
.img3 {
  border:4px solid black;
  border-left:2px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://dev.laurentchevrette.digital/images/pano3.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller container2">
  <div class="img img1"></div>
  <div class="img img2"></div>
  <div class="img img3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you resize the window, the image thumbnails will follow, always keeping the container2's height

Comment: In the snippet, there is still space (besides the deliberate border) between images.  in practice i will often have a lot more than 3 thumbnails, and want to pack them horizontally as close as possible with just a bit of border between each one.

Comment: ok i got that, no problem I'll edit the code. Have you considered using Masonry.js? I'm not a big fan of frameworks and stuff (plugins, etc.) but this is worth it have a look : https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/YzqevVo

Comment: better, but now it's cropping the images if they aren't square.

Comment: no problem, we can overcome that too if the image aren't square.  i just used new images because your source images were very small

Comment: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/YzqevVo there you go with super large panoramic pictures

Comment: since background-position is set to center center (bothX and Y) and background-size set to cover, you get the center of the image. If you want the whole image squeezed in the container, you can change background-size to : contain but then you might have white spaces above and under. The whole idea is that you cant get *any* file format to perfectly fit in a square with no blanks without deforming either the width or the height of the image. So its either a square, a rectangle or a vertical rectangle.

Comment: but i don't want squares, i want to aspect ratio to be preserved... my second "solution" does that, but it does so at the expense of having to pre-define a sufficient width for each image, which also leaves additional unwanted whitespace unless I compute the actual width on a per image basis (which exceeds the scope of CSS).  but, maybe it's not possible using only CSS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221177/discussion-between-laurentc-and-michael).